# XSLT error message in loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print one line error message when first and last name were not found:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Users/User_Detail">
  <xsl:sort select="title" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:sort select="last_name" order="ascending" />
  <xsl:variable name="firstname" select="first_name" />
  <xsl:variable name="lastname" select="last_name" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$lname!='' and $fname !=''">
      <xsl:if test="not(contains($firstname,$fname))">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($lastname,$lname))">
          error
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="not(contains($firstname,$fname))">
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($lastname,$lname))">
<xsl:message terminate="yes">
An error occurred
  </xsl:message>
      error
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is using [xsl:message](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_message.asp) with error handling on processing time which can also terminate the processing if desired:

```
<xsl:if test="contains($lastname,$lname)">
  <xsl:message terminate="no">
    An error occured
  </xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @Martin Honnen: Thanks. I edited the answer accordingly and also removed the trivial approach.

Comment: I just got Empty page, I did not get 'An error occured' message .

Comment: I just tested it and `xsl:message` works as expected. In your case there must be something wrong with the `test="..."` conditions, because if one of them evaluates to `false`, 'xsl:message` would never be reached - hence the empty page.

Comment: I have written hello message after the condition it is printed but error message is not shown

Comment: @kanna: Glad to read that. What XSLT compiler did you use before that, that didn't compliantly implement this feature (I'm just curious ;-)?

Comment: I don't have compiler, I just checked in browser, Thank you

Comment: if possible can you help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512986/issue-while-sending-error-message-in-xslt